# how to reset a lost admin password?

Tags: 12.04, password-recovery

how can I reset a lost administrative password ,considering that Ubuntu and windows7 are both installed on the computer , considering also that "Boot up the machine,and after the BIOS screen, hold down the left Shift key." didn't logged me to any thing, just continue the loading of the system as normal??

Comment: Did you loose your Ubuntu or Windows password?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password should take care of it, but I suspect that the user lost the bios password... he/she is saying that he can't get to the boot menu.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu and windows7 dual boot you can select recovery mode from the grub menu (most probably the 2nd option from top). To press and hold "shift" is not required for you. Then follow the link given by Rmano.

Answer (score 3):

"Boot up the machine,and after the BIOS screen, hold down the left Shift key." Did indeed NOT log you into the machine. That is correct. You are seeing a menu instead. If not, then don't read any further and try again.

If you do see the menu:
Choose "Advanced options", then choose (recovery) from the menu.
Then you see a lot of text passing upward on the screen. Do nothing.
Then you see a colored menu. Choose "root".

Type:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
passwd your_username_here
```

change your password

then type:

```
reboot
```

Comment: I meant that I didn't see the menu after holding the shift key,it had logged to the machine as normal(seem it didn't respond to the shift holding )."and this is the problem here>> I cant arrive to the menu to make settings". I tried to reboot the system and hold shift many times, nothing changed; system continue the loading as normal

Comment: are you the only user on that system ? and can you login as a normal user ?

Comment: If you are really struggling to get to the grub menu you can force it to show. Comment out the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 line https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2