# Forgot ubuntu passwords and would like to start fresh

Tags: updates, password-recovery

I installed ubuntu on a Windows Vista laptop last year, didn't use it much and now am trying to update to newer version and run other updates that it lists, but it asks for my password and I have no idea what it is.  I do not have any files to save as I just used it for internet access so would like to just completely start over, install latest version and not setup passwords, any guidance for someone that is really just savy enough to install a printer driver.

Comment: You can start from here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/

Comment: If you want, you can reset your admin password in this way   
http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Yes,  I thought it would be easier to remove/delete all from the laptop and start fresh, but the step to reset password was very easy and then just had to let it run the updates!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much answered your own question here "I do not have any files to save".

I too recommend you download the latest iso for 14.04 and burn it to a cd or usb stick.

Btw if you previously installed Ubuntu, then I would say you are a bit more savy than if you were only able to install a print driver (which is very easy in Ubuntu).

Comment: I followed some of the posted steps to recover my password and then was able to run updates so am now fixed.  Thanks for your response.  

The part I could not figure out/still can not, I had put the new version on cd and was trying to start up with the cd in to do the update, but it would just open ubuntu.  Then I would go to the cd drive and click to start the update, but it wouldn't do it.  That is the main reason I wanted to try to remove it all.  At least its working now.  Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following link: [Lost Password CLICK HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371634/how-to-reset-a-lost-admin-password)

If you indeed want to start fresh then I would suggest that you download the newest most updated version of Ubuntu which is 14.04 and create a new password/account all together. Might be a great idea if you do not have any important information saved.

Comment: Thanks!  this password reset fixed my issue so I was able to enter my password and let the system process the updates.  (I had downloaded version 14.04 to disk, but even starting the pc with the disk in was either giving me an error or it would open ubuntu, but not let me upgrade without entering the password.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @bbeins: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.