# I have no account in ubuntu

Tags: sudo, users

I just bought a new laptop with ubuntu installed on it. When i first turned on the laptop ubuntu started with an error and restarted. Then when it turned on again i only had the guest session option. I've tried, but i can't use sudo in the terminal:
Sudo: unable to change to root gid: operation not permitted
Sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
I tried the recovery path too, but i don't have a username and can't do anything. I can only go in guest session.
Please help, sorry if this is something obvious to do, it's my first time opening ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to reset a lost admin password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371634/how-to-reset-a-lost-admin-password)

Comment: @user68186 I don't believe the questions are duplicates (They may be similar). According to the OP, in this case, the user isn't created.

Comment: @Dan retracted. I am keeping the comment in case it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reset root password :**

While boot press shift and choose recovery mode :

drop to root shell
then use following commands :

```
mount -o rw,remount /
passwd root
```

**to add new user use :**

```
adduser username
```

and choose a password for the user

finally:

```
reboot
```