# Dell XPS 13 Ubuntu Guest to Administrator

Tags: dell, users, adduser

So, I got Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition, 2018. The laptop started fine, and then it entered the guest account.

There is no way that I can create an administrator user account. I followed the steps provided by Ubuntu.com asking to go to *Settings*->*User Accounts*->'*Unlock*' and then add a new user, but I can neither unlock it nor can I add a new user.

After it booted for the first time, it asked to connect to wifi internet service. And that was not successful initially. But without asking any further questions toward setting up my account, it directly went to the guest account. No administrator account was created.

N.B: Any help is appreciated. And any suggestions to refine the question are most welcome.

Comment: When you turned it on for the first time after taking it out of the box, did you go through the initial setup and account creation? Do you remember the username and password you created at that time? Do you see that name on the login screen if you log out of the guest account? Please your question with more details.

Comment: the initial setup and account creation didn't even start

Comment: You can not do sys admin from the guest account it is confined by apparmor. Boot to recovery mode and create a user and other admin as needed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/371634/how-to-reset-a-lost-admin-password

Comment: No, it is not a duplicate. Pressing the left shift key does not boot into recovery mode. And the other question is about resetting a lost admin password. My system does not have an admin account to begin with

Comment: You may want to call Dell's help line.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of this. I guess, I would rather fresh install ubuntu on a pre-loaded ubuntu system. :P

Comment: I was just looking to buy this on dell's website but all the ubuntu versions seems to have disappeared(!) - perhaps this is the reason why.

Comment: I would like to consider my question to be a duplicate of the question below, instead of what my question is marked to be a duplicate of. But, the answer there doesn't solve my problem.

https://askubuntu.com/q/1006494/329036

Comment: ok, I managed to create an admin account using the answer to the question whose link I posted above